# GCP BigQuery - LIMIT but full table read - How to limit queried data to a minimum

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, sql-execution-plan

It looks like `LIMIT` would have no effect on the amount of processed/queried data (if you trust the UI).

---

[image]

---

```
SELECT
  * --count(*)
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`
-- LIMIT   20
```

How to limit the amount of queried data to a minimum (even though one whole partition would probably always be needed)

- without to use "preview" or similar
- without to know the partition / clustering of the data

How to check the real approximate amount before a query execution?

---

In the execution details is stated that only 163514 rows has been queried as input (not 244928379 rows)

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. You have partitioning and clustering to limit the volume of data scan but, in any case, it's always a full scan which is performed (on the table, the partition,...). The limit only limit the output, not the processing. So, can you be clearer when you say that you don't know the partition? Do you want to count? to select all (*)?

Comment: "Limit 2" -> gives a lot of possibilities. Like taken the last two entries from cache (which could be cached because of current timing of write or read or because it's often used. Analog concepts are present e.g. in cassandra .. -> Goal is to minimize reads/cost and maximize performance. The scenario is that you don't know about partitioning and clustering.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Like the screenshot shows, you are wrong if you say it is a full table scan. Like I wrote is is NOT a full table scan.

Comment: I answered with more detail and example. But I'm not sure that I'm addressing your issue. Can you be more precise?

Answer (score 0):

You pay for the volume of data loaded in the workers. Of course, you do nothing in your request and you ask for the 20 first result, the query stop earlier, and all the data aren't processed, but at least loaded. And you will pay for this!

Have a look to this. I have a similar request
[image]

Now, let's go to the logs
[image]

The total byte billed is ~800Mb

*So you, have to think differently when you work with BigQuery, it's analytics database and not designed to perform small requests (too slow to start, the latency is at least 500ms due to worker warm up).*

---

My table contain 3M+ of rows, and only 10% have been processed
[image]

And you pay for the reservation and the load cost (moving data have a cost and reserving slots has also a cost).

That's why, there is a lot of tip to save money on Google BigQuery. [Some examples by a former BigQuery Dev Advocate](https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b)

Comment: thanks for your answer. The core of the question is that in Execution details it is stated that only 0.067 % of rows (244928379/163514) was read. That is not a full table scan but 794 GB appears to be the full table size. Is that the same in your case? -> Would be crazy to charge for (reading) 244928379 rows but only read 0.067%, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's their pricing model. On the other hand, you can achieve very complex formula and filtering, joining (...) on the same amount of data, for the same cost. Therefore, use BigQuery to transform and deep dive into your data, not to perform usual 'MySQL' query!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the amount of data BQ uses for a query you have this two options:

- **Table Partitioning**
  Big query *can* partition data using either a Date/Datetime/Timemestamp column you provide *or* by insert date (which is good if you have regular updates on a table).

  In order to do this, you must specify the partition strategy in the DDL:

  ```sql
  CREATE TABLE mydataset.mytable (foo: int64, txdate:date)
  PARTITION BY txdate
  ```
- **Wildcard tables** (like Sharding - splitting the data into multiple tables

  This works when your data holds information about different domains (geographical, customer type, etc.) or sources.
  Instead of having one big table, you can create 'subtables' or 'shards' like this with a similar schema (usually people use the same). For instance,`dateset.tablename.eur` for european data and ```dataset.tablename.jap`` for data from Japan.

  You can query one of those tables directll `select col1,col2... from dataset.tablename.custromer_eur;`  or from all tables `select col1,col2 from 'dataset.tablename.*'`

  Wildcard tables can be also partitioned by date.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Regarding the mismatch of full table size/rows and "Execution details" (in reality [only]) read rows would still exists for wildcard tables, right?

Answer (score 0):

as of december 2021, I notice select * from  Limit, will not scan the whole table and you pay only for a small number of rows, obviously if you add order by, it will scan everything.